# Checking a session variable from an include file - PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

When a user logs in to my system, I have a session variable `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;` and then on each page I check the variable to see if the user is logged in or not, which works okay:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
   header("location: https://mydomain.com/cpanel/login.php");
   exit();
}
```

But now, for ease of maintenance, I want to add this session checker to an include file and include it at the top of every secure page. However, each time I log in it fails.

This is what is in the include file:

```
// start session
session_start();

// check login session
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
   header("location: https://mydomain.com/cpanel/login.php");
   exit();
}
```

And this is what I have added to the header of each page:

```
// load authentication file
include "../includes/authentication/check.php";
```

But it appears that the `$_SESSION` is empty, even though I am definitely logged in. I tried removing the `session_start();` from the include file as I thought that might be reetting it somehow - but that wasn't it.

Have any of you guys got a clue as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: "However, each time I log in it fails." - any error message you get?

Comment: @KennyPowers: No error message. The include file sees that the session variable is empty when in-fact the session variable definitely contains the value "1".

Comment: Much likelly, there is problem with creating the session variable - your login script is broken.

Comment: If you print_r($_SESSION); die(); is the $_SESSION array properly printing?

Comment: @TomášZato: My login script is *not* broken. If you read my question it says that checking the session's value on each page (manually, without the include file) works without a problem - but when checking it from the include file it fails.

Comment: Put `print_R($_SESSION)` instead of redirect and exit to see, what is in the session file. As well, create standalone `display_session.php` containing just `session_start(); print_R($_SESSION)` to see session contents.

Comment: Can you create a simple three-file example - an include file, and two other files that include the include file, read the session info and echo it to the browser, set a variable, and a link call the other file. This would be the simplest structure to debug from - without "login" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **include_once** because with **include** every time include **session_start();** become run  I Think Problem is this